# Finding the Process which resulted in Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, kernel, crash

I have setup my linux system to generate Kernel Core Dump using KDump and kexec packages.  I am using the crash tool to analyze the core dump.  How do I find the call stack of the process which resulted in the kernel call that crashed?  Also, is it possible to include all the running process Call Stack in the Kernel Core Dump?  What other useful information could be extracted from Kernel Core Dump?

Comment: A process can not cause a kernel panic. Only bugs in the kernel can cause it.